# How to multiply each row in RDD with each other?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cartesian-product

I have a RDD which is similar to,

```
CELL-ID | COUNT
--------------
abcd       10
DEF        20
ghi        15
```

I need to get an RDD with

```
CELL-ID-1 | CELL-ID-2 | PRODUCT
--------------
abcd       DEF            200
abcd       ghi            150
DEF        abcd           200
DEF        ghi            300
...
....
```

How can this be done ? I've tied to use cartesian product but couldn't get the output

```
val result = orginalRDD.cartesian(orginalRDD).collect {
  case ((t1: _,Int), (t2: _,Int)) if t1 != t2 => t1 * t2
}
```

Comment: If `originalRDD` is a large dataset, perhaps the `.collect()` simply won't fit in the driver program's memory. You don't mention why you couldn't get the output, so we can only speculate.

Comment: It's pretty big RDD, 6M+ records, should this code be ported to 'map' or something else

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken... See @tzach-zohar's reply to my comment on his answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can either make `t1` and `t2` represent the *tuples* (entire "records"):

```
val result = orginalRDD.cartesian(orginalRDD).collect {
  case (t1: (String ,Int), t2: (String ,Int)) if t1 != t2 => (t1._1, t2._1, t1._2 * t2._2)
}
```

Or, you can do the same but use the pattern-matching to break them up further:

```
val result = orginalRDD.cartesian(orginalRDD).collect {
  case (t1@(s1 ,i1), t2@(s2, i2)) if t1 != t2 => (s1, s2, i1 * i2)
}
```

Your solution looks like an attempt to do both at once...

Comment: I'd recommend a `.map()` here instead of a `.collect()`. The `.collect()` call will bring the filtered cartesian result back to the driver program's heap. It's not an issue with this toy data set, but with a large distributed data set the result would be quite large.

Comment: @TravisHegner that's not true - although the name might seem confusing, this specific overload of `RDD.collect` does NOT send data back to driver, it's a simple mapping-and-filtering by applying a partial function. Actually, its implementation is as simple as `filter(f.isDefinedAt).map(f)`, see https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/cd0a08361e2526519e7c131c42116bf56fa62c76/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L958-L961

Comment: @TzachZohar the code seems to work but when I print the RDD, there is nothing in it. only a () is printed.. Any idea why ?                                                                                       
    val result = originalRDD.cartesian(originalRDD).collect {
      case (t1: (String ,Int), t2: (String ,Int)) if t1 != t2 => (t1._1, t2._1, t1._2 * t2._2)
    }
    print(result.take(5).foreach(println))

Comment: Worked for me for some sample data... and why are you printing the result of `foreach(println)` (which already prints...)? `result.take(5).foreach(println)` should be enough.

Comment: ah my mistake on print, but I'm not sure why I'm not getting any output in the console or in HDFS.

Comment: @TzachZohar can we avoid the Cartesian join to optimize this scenario ? Cluster fails when doing this Cartesian product operation